# If element width more than 80%

Tags: jquery, width

Tell me please how can I made function right

```
var $photoblock = $(".element img");
if ($photoblock).width() > 80%){
$photoblock.css({width: 80%, max-width: 'none'});
} else {
$photoblock.css({width: auto, max-width: 100%});
});
```

How would be right?

Comment: This is size of my picture. If width would be more than 80% of parent, image should be 80%, and if it less than 80% it should have the original size.

Comment: Not sure what you want to do, but in any case: .width() will return a string with just the width, not a 80% as you have. Besides the errors, the function of the code seems a bit weird: you select all images. When they are larger than 80% (of something?), you make them 80%, when they are smaller than that, you make them 100% (of something?)? What should be the effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this

```
var $photoblock = $(".element img");
var per = $photoblock.parent().width() * 0.8;
if ($photoblock.width() > per) {
    $photoblock.css({
        width: '80%',
        'max-width': 'none'
    });
} else {
    $photoblock.css({
        width: 'auto',
        'max-width': '100%'
    });
}
```

`$photoblock.width()`    will return the width in pixel not in percentage. Hence you need to find out the 80% of it's parent and then need to compare it.

Answer (score 1):

The .width() does not give the width in %, so compare it against the width of the parent, also there are few other syntax issues

```
var $photoblock = $(".element img"),
    $parent = $photoblock.parent();
if ($photoblock).width() > $parent.width() * .8) {
    $photoblock.css({
        width: '80%',
        'max-width': 'none'
    });
} else {
    $photoblock.css({
        width: 'auto',
        'max-width': '100%'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the css width (if specified in percentage), then parseInt it to get the value which you can use in calculation or comparision:

```
if (parseInt($photoblock.css('width')) > 80){..
```

Otherwise, compare it with the parents width (as suggested by other posters):

```
if ($photoblock).width() > $parent.width() * .8) { ...
```